# Scala -Create Map from Spark DataFrame

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary

I have a Spark DataFrame and I want to create Map and store values as Map[String, Map[String, String]].
I am not getting idea to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Below is Input and Output Format :

Input :

```
    +-----------------+------------+---+--------------------------------+
    |relation         |obj_instance|obj|map_value                       |
    +-----------------+------------+---+--------------------------------+
    |Start~>HInfo~>Mnt|Mnt         |Mnt|[Model -> 2000, Version -> 1.0] |
    |Start~>HInfo~>Cbl|Cbl-3       |Cbl|[VSData -> XYZVN, Name -> Smart]|
    +-----------------+------------+---+--------------------------------+
```

Output :

```
    Map(relation -> Start~>HInfo~>Mnt, obj_instance -> Mnt, obj -> Mnt, Mnt -> Map(Model -> 2000, Version -> 1.0))
    Map(relation -> Start~>HInfo~>Cbl, obj_instance -> Cbl-3, obj -> Cbl, Cbl -> Map(VSData -> XYZVN, Name -> Smart))
```

Code, I'm trying but not success :

```
   var resultMap: Map[Any, Any] = Map()
   groupedDataSet.foreach( r => {
     val key1 = "relation".toString
     val value1 = r(0).toString
     val key2 = "obj_instance".toString
     val value2 = r(1).toString
     val key3 = "obj".toString
     val value3 = r(2).toString
     val key4 = r(2).toString
     val value4 = r(3)

     resultMap += (key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2, key3 -> value3, key4 -> value4)
   })
     resultMap.foreach(println)
```

Please help.

Below is the Code to create Test DataFrame and Map Column

```
            import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
            import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, SparkSession}
            import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

            object DFToMap extends App {

              //Creating SparkSession
              lazy val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("df-to-map").set("spark.default.parallelism", "2")
                .setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")
              lazy val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

              import sparkSession.implicits._

    // Creating raw DataFrame
          val rawTestDF = Seq(("Start~>HInfo~>Cbl", "Cbl-3", "Cbl", "VSData", "XYZVN"), ("Start~>HInfo~>Cbl", "Cbl-3", "Cbl", "Name", "Smart"),
            ("Start~>HInfo~>Mnt", "Mnt", "Mnt", "Model", "2000"), ("Start~>HInfo~>Mnt", "Mnt", "Mnt", "Version", "1.0"))
            .toDF("relation", "obj_instance", "obj", "key", "value")

          rawTestDF.show(false)

    val joinTheMap = udf { json_value: Seq[Map[String, String]] => json_value.flatten.toMap }

          val groupedDataSet = rawTestDF.groupBy("relation", "obj_instance", "obj").agg(collect_list(map(col("key"), col("value"))) as "map_value_temp").withColumn("map_value", joinTheMap(col("map_value_temp")))
            .drop("map_value_temp")

          groupedDataSet.show(false)  //This is the Input DataFrame.


            }
```

Final Output Json from Map :

```
    [{"relation":"Start~>HInfo~>Mnt","obj_instance":"Mnt","obj":"Mnt","Mnt":{"Model":"2000","Version":"1.0"}}
    {"relation":"Start~>HInfo~>Cbl","obj_instance":"Cbl-3","obj:"Cbl","Cbl":{"VSData":"XYZVN","Name":"Smart"}}]
```

Note : I don't want to use any Spark groupBy, pivot, agg as Spark streaming doesn't support multi aggregation. Hence I want to get it with pure Scala code. Kindly help.

Comment: Can you post your dataframe schema & create dataframe if you have already ?

Comment: Hi Srinivas, I have the code/class created to get this Output, Please help if you can to convert entitre Data Frame to Map and finally have to convert as Json.

Comment: sure, i can help you if you give me final json output & input of dataframe.

Comment: can you explain this - India -> Map(city -> Delhi, size -> L) how are you mapping

Comment: also post your final json output here ?

Comment: Hi Srinaivas, I have updated input and output format in question. Same output I can get using Spark functions but I have to avoid due to Streaming restrictions, So want to get same output using pure Scala code using Map collection.  If possible please help :(

Comment: Can i know what are streaming restrictions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created custom `UDF` to parse & generate data in JSON format.

```
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

  def toJson(relation:String,obj_instance: String,obj: String,map_value: Map[String,String]) = {
    compact(render(
      JObject("relation" -> JString(relation),
        "obj_instance" -> JString(obj_instance),
        "obj" -> JString(obj),
        obj -> map_value)))
  }

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  val createJson = udf(toJson _)
  val df = Seq(("Start~>HInfo~>Mnt","Mnt","Mnt",Map("Model" -> "2000", "Version" -> "1.0")),("Start~>HInfo~>Cbl","Cbl-3","Cbl",Map("VSData" -> "XYZVN", "Name" -> "Smart"))).toDF("relation","obj_instance","obj","map_value")
  df.select(createJson($"relation",$"obj_instance",$"obj",$"map_value").as("json_map")).show(false)


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_map                                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"relation":"Start~>HInfo~>Mnt","obj_instance":"Mnt","obj":"Mnt","Mnt":{"Model":"2000","Version":"1.0"}}   |
|{"relation":"Start~>HInfo~>Cbl","obj_instance":"Cbl-3","obj":"Cbl","Cbl":{"VSData":"XYZVN","Name":"Smart"}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, Thanks for your prompt answer, but if you look into updated Question, My Input DataFrame has one Map column, hence this may not help as it needs only same datatype.

Comment: Cast that map datatype column to string and pass to map spark function.

Comment: Same I have done in the answer where country India has map of values.

Comment: Earlier I had tried to cast Map Column as String and was getting the expected output but while I tried to convert to Json, it was not as expected as given below, hence Struggling for the solution.   {"relation":"Start~>HInfo~>Mnt","obj_instance":"Mnt","obj":"Mnt","Mnt":"[Model -> 2000, Version -> 1.0]}

Comment: How are you converting map to json ?

Comment: Please check now, I have update answer & convert map to json using spark toJSON method.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas, but inner map is not converting to json, it's still looks map in json output :)

Comment: one last try ..:) .. let me know if it is not working.

Comment: I had tried this as well.... but  pattern  \    in inner json is not acceptable in project and can't use regex replace due to performance issue with dataset in TB.

Comment: This was the reason, I was looking for pure Scala collection based solution  :)

Comment: I have created UDF to generate JSON data from given columns & update answer.

Comment: take mail from my profile page. Thank You for accepting this answer.

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, Can you please help me with this question? I'm stuck at last stage of project.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457624/how-to-avoid-using-of-collect-in-spark-rdd-in-scala