# How to avoid using of collect in Spark RDD in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, persist, collect

I have a List and has to create Map from this for further use, I am using RDD, but with use of collect(), job is failing in cluster. Any help is appreciated.

Please help. Below is the sample code from List to rdd.collect.
I have to use this Map data further but how to use without collect?

This code creates a Map from RDD (List) Data. List Format->(asdfg/1234/wert,asdf)

```
 //List Data to create Map
 val listData = methodToGetListData(ListData).toList
//Creating RDD from above List  

  val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD(listData)

      implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
      val res = rdd
        .map(map => (getRPath(map._1), getAttribute(map._1), map._2))
        .groupBy(_._1)
        .map(tuple => {
          Map(
            "P_Id" -> "1234",
            "R_Time" -> "27-04-2020",
            "S_Time" -> "27-04-2020",
            "r_path" -> tuple._1,
            "S_Tag" -> "12345,
            tuple._1 -> (tuple._2.map(a => (a._2, a._3)).toMap)
          )
        })

      res.collect()
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample input & output  ?

Comment: How is it failing? Is that an out of memory error? And how are you using the collected data?

Comment: List : Input List : List((Start~>HInfo~>Monitor~>VSData,XYZVN), (Start~>HInfo~>Cables~>Cables-1~>Name,LC), (Start~>HInfo~>Disk~>Disk-1~>Partition~>Partition-1~>Name,Not Used))

Comment: Example Output Map :  Map(Item_Id -> -0909, Parent_Id -> 1234, object_class_instance -> Cables-3, Received_Time -> 23-12-2020, Cables -> Map(Index -> 2, Status -> Installed, HInfoID -> ABCD1234, Name -> WLAN), object_class -> Cables, ServiceTag -> ASDF123, Scan_Time -> 12345, relation_tree -> Start~>HInfo~>Cables~>Cables-3)

Comment: Map(Item_Id -> -0909, Parent_Id -> 1234, object_class_instance -> Cables-1, Received_Time -> 23-12-2020, Cables -> Map(Name -> LC, Status -> Installed, HInfoID -> ABCD1234, Index -> 0), object_class -> Cables, ServiceTag -> ASDF123, Scan_Time -> 12345, relation_tree -> Start~>HInfo~>Cables~>Cables-1)

Comment: Error is task is bigger Size, recommended 100 MB and not returning output after hours also, I am using res.collect() at last to return the Map Data.

Comment: Hi @ernest_k, after collecting the Map Data, I have to further Convert into Json and collect all the json file in a single Array.

Comment: @Srinivas, Can you please have a look to your mail, shared sample code to get Input/Output.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use an RDD? And if so, why can't you convert to json in the RDD? Also the error you mention sounds like an informational message, or a warning at best.

Comment: ok, i will check that.

Comment: @Jasper, If you don't mind, can you please share your mail ID, I can share the actual Code, and see if you can help with some modifications.?

Comment: check the answer.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> Q: how to use without collect?

---

> Answer : `collect` will hit.. it will move the data to driver node. if data is
>   huge. Never do that.

---

I dont exactly know what is the use case to prepare a `map` but it can be achievable ***using built in spark API*** i.e.**`collectionAccumulator`** ... in detail,

***`collectionAccumulator[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]`***

---

Lets suppose, this is your sample dataframe and you want to make a map.

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|Item_Id|Parent_Id|object_class_instance|Received_Time|CablesName|CablesStatus|CablesHInfoID|CablesIndex|object_class|ServiceTag|Scan_Time|relation_tree                  |
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|-0909  |1234     |Cables-1             |23-12-2020   |LC        |Installed   |ABCD1234     |0          |Cables      |ASDF123   |12345    |Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-1 |
|-09091 |1234111  |Cables-11            |23-12-2022   |LC1       |Installed1  |ABCD12341    |0          |Cables1     |ASDF1231  |123451   |Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-11|
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

From this you want to make a map (***nested map I prefixed with nestedmap key name in your example***) then...

Below is the full example have a look and modify accordingly.

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level

object GrabMapbetweenClosure extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)


  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName(this.getClass.getName)
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  var mutableMapAcc = spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]("mutableMap")

  val df = Seq(
    ("-0909", "1234", "Cables-1", "23-12-2020", "LC", "Installed", "ABCD1234"
      , "0", "Cables", "ASDF123", "12345", "Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-1")
    , ("-09091", "1234111", "Cables-11", "23-12-2022", "LC1", "Installed1", "ABCD12341"
      , "0", "Cables1", "ASDF1231", "123451", "Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-11")

  ).toDF("Item_Id", "Parent_Id", "object_class_instance", "Received_Time", "CablesName", "CablesStatus", "CablesHInfoID",
    "CablesIndex", "object_class", "ServiceTag", "Scan_Time", "relation_tree"
  )

  df.show(false)
  df.foreachPartition { partition => // for performance sake I used foreachPartition
    partition.foreach {
      record => {
        mutableMapAcc.add(scala.collection.mutable.Map(
          "Item_Id" -> record.getAs[String]("Item_Id")
          , "CablesStatus" -> record.getAs[String]("CablesStatus")
          , "CablesHInfoID" -> record.getAs[String]("CablesHInfoID")
          , "Parent_Id" -> record.getAs[String]("Parent_Id")
          , "CablesIndex" -> record.getAs[String]("CablesIndex")
          , "object_class_instance" -> record.getAs[String]("object_class_instance")
          , "Received_Time" -> record.getAs[String]("Received_Time")
          , "object_class" -> record.getAs[String]("object_class")
          , "CablesName" -> record.getAs[String]("CablesName")
          , "ServiceTag" -> record.getAs[String]("ServiceTag")
          , "Scan_Time" -> record.getAs[String]("Scan_Time")
          , "relation_tree" -> record.getAs[String]("relation_tree")

        )
        )
      }
    }
  }
  println("FinalMap : " + mutableMapAcc.value.toString)

}
```

Result :

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|Item_Id|Parent_Id|object_class_instance|Received_Time|CablesName|CablesStatus|CablesHInfoID|CablesIndex|object_class|ServiceTag|Scan_Time|relation_tree                  |
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|-0909  |1234     |Cables-1             |23-12-2020   |LC        |Installed   |ABCD1234     |0          |Cables      |ASDF123   |12345    |Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-1 |
|-09091 |1234111  |Cables-11            |23-12-2022   |LC1       |Installed1  |ABCD12341    |0          |Cables1     |ASDF1231  |123451   |Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-11|
+-------+---------+---------------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+

FinalMap : [Map(Scan_Time -> 123451, ServiceTag -> ASDF1231, Received_Time -> 23-12-2022, object_class_instance -> Cables-11, CablesHInfoID -> ABCD12341, Parent_Id -> 1234111, Item_Id -> -09091, CablesIndex -> 0, object_class -> Cables1, relation_tree -> Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-11, CablesName -> LC1, CablesStatus -> Installed1), Map(Scan_Time -> 12345, ServiceTag -> ASDF123, Received_Time -> 23-12-2020, object_class_instance -> Cables-1, CablesHInfoID -> ABCD1234, Parent_Id -> 1234, Item_Id -> -0909, CablesIndex -> 0, object_class -> Cables, relation_tree -> Start~>HInfo->Cables->Cables-1, CablesName -> LC, CablesStatus -> Installed)]
```

[Similar problem was solved here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57482517/647053)

Comment: Hi @Ram Ghadiyaram, This is working fine, but the real code is unning fine with rdd, while I'm tryng to convert List to DF(), I'm getting NULL Pointer Exception.    val listData = (relationData).toList
      val rawDF = listData.toDF("rln_tr", "attr_val")
      rawDF.show(false)  //RawDF has NULL Pointer Exception
      val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD(listData)// This is working fine

Comment: But you have to identify where you are doing operation on null i.m not sure with your data.

Comment: I say BIG NO to collect